# I can't use python pip to download any tools and I don't know why

Tags: python3, pip, python-2.7

here's a picture of the error I get and the python installations i have, I tried to delete python7.2 and it seems like it's not working.. any help is highly appreciated
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The package name is `python3-pip`:

```
$ sudo apt install python3-pip
```

You can also use `get-pip.py` to install `pip`:

```
$ curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
$ python get-pip.py
```

After installation was finished you can use `pip` to install your desired packages. for example:

```
$ pip3 install virtualenv
```